# How to format WPF timer to HH:MM:SS

Tags: c#, wpf

Im working on a program that displays time from when you clicked a button. The issue is that the time is displayed as just "1", "2", "3" etc.. when I would like it to be displayed as "00:00:01", "00:00:02"

This is in WPF. I have searched all over to find people saying you use

```
increment.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss\\);
```

but when I do this it literally shows "hh:mm:ss" in my program. Below is my code. I cut off the unimportant stuff so you don't have to read thru all that. Thanks in advance!

```
    private int increment = 0;

    private void dtTicker(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        increment++;
        lblTest.Content = increment.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.fff");

    }

    private void StartStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();

        if ((string)StartStop.Content == "START")
        {
            dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            dt.Tick += dtTicker;
            dt.Start();
```

Comment: Increment is a number, you have to use `TimeSpan` or `DateTime` for the formatting to work. BTW `TimeSpan.ToString()` returns the value formatted the way you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get your elapsed time without counting the times when the timer was stopped, you should store two values:

```
/// <summary>
/// Global counter that increments while the timer is active
/// </summary>
private TimeSpan totalElapsed = new TimeSpan(0);
/// <summary>
/// Save the last relevant point in time to compute the next elapsed increment
/// </summary>
private DateTime lastPointInTime = DateTime.MinValue;
```

Initialize `lastPointInTime` when the timer (re-)starts

```
dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
dt.Tick += dtTicker;
// reset lastPointInTime in order to skip time from when the timer was stopped
lastPointInTime = DateTime.Now;
dt.Start();
```

And use it for each tick in order to update `totalElapsed` before displaying it

```
var nextPointInTime = DateTime.Now;
totalElapsed += (nextPointInTime - lastPointInTime);
lastPointInTime = nextPointInTime;
lblTest.Content = totalElapsed.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"); // format string optional
```

Answer (score 3):

The format string you're using is meant for a DateTime and TimeSpan, not integer. You can't actually rely on DispatchTimer being 100% accurate, so make a note of the current time when you start it:

```
private DateTime start;

// .. start timer...
start = DateTime.Now;
```

Then in your tick handler calculate the elapsed time and pass in that format string you're using:

```
TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - start;
string str = elapsed.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
```

Comment: `DateTime.Now - start` causes the timer to reset the timer each time I click StartStop. Any way around this?

Comment: Sure, just set it to DateTime.Now when you first initialize the timer instead of every time you start it.

Answer (score 2):

Your Timer is configured with interval as 1 second.Unless you alter variable increment else where, increment should reflect number of seconds elapsed.

To display in required format, you can convert the number to TimeSpan using TimeSpan.FromSeconds

```
var increment = 34;
lblTest.Content =TimeSpan.FromSeconds(increment).ToString();
```

Please note the default formatting is "hh:mm:ss", so you can skip formatting'

Output

```
00:00:34
```

Comment: @gdoron I thought default formatting is "hh:mm:ss". That's why i skipped it

Answer (score 0):

You are operating under the false assumption that `DispatcherTimer` will fire it's `Tick` event exactly each second. This is not necessarily the case.
What you want to do is take the time when it's started, and show the amount of time passed after that in each tick. Something like this:

```
private TimeSpan timeElapsed = TimeSpan.Zero;
private DateTime started = DateTime.MinValue;

private void StartStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();

    if ((string)StartStop.Content == "START")
    {
        dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        dt.Tick += dtTicker;
        started = DateTime.Now;
        dt.Start();
    }
}

private void dtTicker(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timeElapsed = timeElapsed.Add(DateTime.Now - started);
    lblTest.Content = (timeElapsed).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");

}

// This is how you reset the timer in this version.
private void ResetTimer()
{
    timeElapsed = TimeSpan.Zero;
}
```

Comment: `(DateTime.Now - started)`

causes the timer to reset the timer each time I click StartStop. Any way around this?

Comment: Yes. I've edited my answer to show how. Note I've also added a bool field called `resetTimer` that you can use to reset the timer if you want to.

Comment: You are giving me very helpful advice and I appreciate that. However, the current updates make it a continuous timer. If I stop the timer, then it will show the time I stopped it at, but as soon as I resume it then it will add on all the elapsed time as well. Is it possible to make it so I can stop it at a certain time, then resume it at that exact time? Thanks!

Comment: Sure. I've edited my answer once again. I've added a `TimeSpan` field that will represent the time passed when `dt` is running. I've also changed back the setting of the `started` to each time you are starting the timer, and added a method to reset the display.